# Global catalog: Cannot find user via powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, domain, ldap

#### Short description

My customer has a multidomain forest. I recently found at least one user, that I cannot find by the parameter `identity` via a powershell `Get-AdUser` query.

#### Info about the user

DistinguishedName= CN=User01,OU=USR,DC=SubDomain,DC=Domain,DC=TLD
Enabled= True 
GivenName= GivenName
Name= User01
ObjectClass= User
SamAccountName= User01
Surname= Surname
UserPrincipalName= User01@Subdomain.Domain.TLD

#### What i tried successful:

- Find the user by querying the domain direct `Get-AdUser User01 -Server Domain`
- Find the user by querying the domains `GC` by `Get-AdUser User01 -server Domain:3268`
- Find the user by quering the forest `GC` with powershell `Filter {SamAccountName -eq User01}`
- Find the user by querying the forests `GC` by the `.Net` type `DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` by using the `Searchroot = 'GC://DC=Domain,DC=TLD'`

#### What does not work:

- Find the user by quering the forests `GC` by powershell like `Get-AdUser User01 -server Forest:3268`

#### Question:

Why is it, that I can't find the user by the last query?
I don't see a point why I cannot find him via forests `GC` by his username

Comment: Does each domain have multiple DCs? Otherwise you might just be lucky that you're hitting the GC? Have a look at the question [Using a global catalog in powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654523/using-a-global-catalog-in-powershell) which has a snipped to get the actual GC server for the query.

Comment: The childdomains (there are 17 of them) have at least 2 DC each. They all have `GC` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

**I know this thread is old but just trying to help others.**

The following solution will search a user from all child domains of a forest.
Try to use any FQDN of a DC with Global catalogue in your search.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity abcd -Server ForestDcFQDN:3268
```

Or try following command which will get a Forest DC FQDN dynamically

```
$GC = (Get-ADForest).SchemaMaster+":3268" 
Get-ADUser -Identity abcd -Server $GC
```